# Given a list, How to count items in that list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, count

Given the list

```
List2 = ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Black', 'Black', 'Black', 'Green', 'Green', 'Red', 'Yellow']
```

I am trying to figure out how to count how many times each element in the list appears. This has to be incredibly simple but I can't figure it out. I read in my book about the count function and I decided to try to implement it. I thought it would be..

```
for item in List2:
    newlist=[List2.count()]
```

I thought this would lead me to what I wanted:

```
newlist=[3,3,2,1,1]
```

But I received a TypeError saying count has to have an argument. I'm extremely new to python so dumb everything down as much as possible if you could.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections#collections.Counter) which gives you a `dict` like object (in that it also has some additional functionality useful for *count* like purposes) that has key as the item, and a value as the number of occurrences.

```
from collections import Counter


>>> li = ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Black','Black','Black','Green','Green','Red','Yellow']    
>>> Counter(li)
Counter({'Black': 3, 'Apple': 3, 'Green': 2, 'Yellow': 1, 'Red': 1})
```

Then it's up to you to sort that how you'd like it presented...

One (inefficient) way to preseve the order, would be to count, then index into the original list:

```
>>> counts = Counter(li)
>>> [counts[key] for key in sorted(counts, key=li.index)]
[3, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```

An alternative is to use `groupby` (but this relies on the items being consecutive):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(li)]
[3, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: to preserve order, you could use `class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict): pass`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'm humbled - that has never occurred to me :( Thank you so much

Comment: From the sample input, it looks like the items are expected to be consecutive… in which case `groupby` is probably the best solution. (I'd probably use an `ilen` function instead of just putting `len(list(g))` into the comprehension, but YAGNI.)

Comment: @abarnert I'm sure we've had answers with time-it's that show that for smaller amounts of data - `len(list(...))` is more efficient than `sum(1 for i in ...)` equiv... I prefer the later, but... oh well

Comment: @JonClements: That's exactly why I'd make a function. It probably won't matter, and I'll probably have very small groups anyway, so I can just code `ilen` as `len(list(x))`. (Or, even simpler, use `more_itertools.ilen`.) But if I ever need to test it, or change it, I only need to do so in one place. But as I said, YAGNI, especially on a simple homework problem.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Are you sure that works? It does seem to work for me with the OP's exact test case in 2.7.2, but add one more `'Yellow'` and it gives me the `'Yellow': 2` before the `'Red': 1`. And in 3.3.0, it doesn't even work with the OP's test case. So, I think you just got lucky here, and it doesn't work in general.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Looking into it a bit further, I think your `OrderedCounter` is _storing_ the data correctly, but _displaying_ it in random order. That's why the recipe in the `docs` has a `__repr__` method (which makes sure to defer to the `OrderedDict` `repr` instead of the `Counter` one). They also have a `__reduce__`, so I'm guessing it also pickles as a `Counter`, in random order, without that.

Comment: @abarnert: It does work including with one more 'Yellow' and Python 3.3.0: [`newlist = list(OrderedCounter(List2).values())`](http://ideone.com/bexdEq). As the recipe from the docs shows, you need to override `__repr__`, `__reduce__` if you use them (they are not used to get `newlist`)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Please read the comment directly above your last comment.

Comment: @abarnert: show example where `OrderedCounter` produces incorrect `newlist`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: You clearly haven't read the comment above. Please read it before replying again.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to Python I think that is better for you to code the solution instead of just importing something. Here's a simple and easy to understand way to do it:

```
counter = {}
for elem in List2:
    counter[elem] = counter.get(elem, 0) + 1
```

Comment: I don't agree with that first sentence. It's better to learn how to use the "batteries included", and generally to look for simpler and higher-level solutions. Both new programmers, and programmers coming from a language like C or Java, are going to need that skill to become good Python programmers. It's _also_ worth learning how to do things yourself, for those cases where you can't find the batteries you need (or want to extend one that you found). But learning _only_ from the bottom up is not a good idea.

Comment: @abarnert `from collections import Counter` makes you a "good Python programmer"? I deeply disagree

Comment: Knowing how to find the tools you need, and how to use them, makes you a good Python programmer. Someone who can build a half-assed fragile HTML parser from scratch in two weeks is a lot less helpful than someone who can find BeautifulSoup, read the docs, and write useful code in two hours.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
new_list = [List2.count(x) for x in set(List2)]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
new_list = []
for x in set(List2):
    new_list.append(List2.count(x))
```

Or for a dictionary:

```
new_dict = {x:List2.count(x) for x in set(List2)}
```

Comment: @JonClements Yes your is clearly more efficient, but this one is just a "no-import" alternative...